# Is this possible to make navbar attach to top?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlKVt.png)

I want to make my navbar attach to  the top  how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS property `position:fixed` on your navbar in the CSS.
And you are good to go.